# Why is the if-part in my program never true?

Tags: python

This is my first program and this is just the part of the code that's not working. I don't know what is wrong and if someone can help me I will be happy. The problem happens when you win, instead of printing the `if` part, it prints the `else` part.

```
import re

import random 

def game ():
    while True: 
        print("Welcome to heads or tails")

        N = input("""Amount of money to bet :
$""")
        n = int(N)
        r = range (0,101,10)
        if n in r:
            print ("Start the game!!" )
            T = input ("""How many heads?
 """)
            t= int(T)
            a= range (0,11)
            if t in a :
                B = input("""How many tails?
 """)
                b=int(B)
                if b in a and b+t== 10:



                    headsCount = 0
                    tailsCount = 0
                    count = 0

                    while count < 10 :
                        coin = random.randrange(2)
                        if coin == 0:
                            headsCount +=1
                            print ("Heads")
                        else:
                            tailsCount +=1
                            print ("Tails")
                        count +=1
                    score1= str(headsCount)
                    score2= str(tailsCount)
                    print (score1 + " times it was heads")
                    print (score2 + " times it was tails")

#Here is where i think the problem is        
                    if headsCount==t and tailsCount==b:
                        print("You winn!")
                    else :
                        print("Try again, i'm sure that this time you're       going to win!")
                        x = input("""press p to continue or q to exit
 """ )
                        if x== ("q"):
                            print('godbye, see you soon!')
                            break
                        if x == ("p"):
                            game()
            if b in a and b+t< 10:
                print ("You have to select more times")

    else:
        print ("Multiples of 10 only")
game ()
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but make sure you put your import statements at the beginning of your script, not in the body of the code, man.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if score1==t and score2==b:
```

`t` and `b` are integers, and `score1` and `score2` are strings. A string will never compare equal to an integer, so your `if` clause will never be true.

Try changing it to:

```
if headsCount==t and tailsCount==b:
```